# How to get two values to the JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I have a requirement to show two bean variable in the same line in h:outputText. Please advise the various ways to accomplish the same

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have a requirement to make a lot of money before I am 50 years old. Please advise the various ways to accomplish the same. I'm kind of kidding, but if this is your current problem and you were not able to find a solution to this, please take a step back and start with some tutorials on basic plain html web development first. Only after that start with some basic JSF tutorials, and only after that, start developping applications...

Answer (score 2):

```
<h:outputText value="#{ebookController.infoMessage}  #{ebookController.description}"></h:outputText>
```